# Does this series have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

A friend of mine asked me if I could find a closed form for the series:
$$
S = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (n-h)^{\alpha} e^{-\beta(n-h)^2},
$$
with $\alpha,\beta > 0$.

I don't even know how to tackle the problem TBH, but it caught my attention and I'd like to know how to solve it.

Comment: The $h$ can be set to 0 after a shift of index. Are $\alpha,\beta$ integers?

Comment: @AlexR. I think they are real numbers, but solving that particular case would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** $~h$ is and integer **and** *a* is an even integer, then the series can be expressed in terms of the

derivative of order $\dfrac a2$ with regard to *b* of the [Jacobi $\theta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) $~\theta_3\Big(0,e^{-b}\Big),~$ where $\theta_3(0,x)$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{n^2}$